# Unable to access Weblogic datasource through JNDI name using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, weblogic, datasource, jndi, weblogic12c

I am using Weblogic 12c and I have configured my datasources like this:

[image]

Notice that they are all deployed on target "AdminServer". Also, the "Name" field and "JNDI Name" field are identical. For example, suppose one datasource's name is "MYDS".

Now, when I try to acquire that datasource through Spring Data JPA like this:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource businessDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        dataSource.setResourceRef(true);
        dataSource.setJndiName("MYDS");
        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        return (DataSource) dataSource.getObject();
    }
```

I get the following error when trying to deploy the war file to weblogic:

> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'businessDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'MYDS'. Resolved
>   ''; remaining name 'MYDS'

Also I see this error:

> DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean - Converted JNDI name
>   [java:comp/env/MYDS] not found - trying original name [MYDS].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up
>   comp/env/MYDS in /app/myapp/webclient/404708050.; remaining name
>   'comp/env/MYDS'

Comment: Has your problem been solved? How?

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Since I left the company that was having that problem, I don't know whether it was solved, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the source for setResourceRef and it states :

public void setResourceRef(boolean resourceRef)

Set whether the lookup occurs in a Java EE container,

i.e. if the prefix "java:comp/env/" needs to be added if the JNDI name doesn't already contain it. 
Default is "false".

Note: Will only get applied if no other scheme (e.g. "java:") is given.

If you are setting it to true have you tried adding java:comp/env/ to the JNDI name ?